# LS decision boundary

Tags: self-study, classification, least-squares

I was following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22493855/6651940) solution on the least squares classification. I understand up to the point that we get a least square solution but I don't know how to use it to define the decision boundary. In other words, how does this solution help us to find the line. I mean, where does

```
y = -z(3)/z(2) - (z(1)/z(2))*x
```

come from?

Comment: @3lectrologos : I saw the last two comments you wrote on the original post and thought you might now the answer.

Comment: @JSuar : I saw the last comment you wrote on the original post and thought you might now the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer that you cite switches notation and so is a little confusing.  I will try to push it through using more consistent notation.

Using the notation $\vec X = (X_1, X_2)$, the original discussion proposes finding a linear function
    $f(\vec X) = z_1*X_1 + z_2*X_2 + z_3$
that does the best possible job of fittng $f(\vec X) = 1$ when $\vec X$ is in class 1 
and $f(\vec X) = -1$ when $\vec X$ is in class 2. When you want to predict the class of a new point $\vec X$ you compute $f(\vec X)$. If $f(\vec X)$, is closer to 1 you predict class 1. If $f(\vec X)$, is closer to -1 you predict class 2. Obviously, the decision boundary is the line $f(\vec X) = 0$  (halfway between -1 and +1).  So you have to solve
      $0 = z_1*X_1 + z_2*X_2 + z_3$
which yields
 $ X_2 = -z_3/z_2  -  z_1*X_1/z_2  $

This is the equation plotted in the answer that you cited, except that the solution uses x for $X_1$ and y for $X_2$.

Comment: " If [...] is closer to 1 you predict class 1. If [...] is closer to -1 you predict class 2. "  Maybe?  There are many decision boundaries, depending on how much evidence you require to decide one class over the other.  Decision making should take into accounts the costs of false negatives and positives, and true negatives and positives.  I think you should say "One way to decide the predicted class of a new data point is to...", which leave explicitly open that sometimes you wouldnt want to do that.

Comment: I agree that there are other ways of deciding the decision boundary. I was addressing the question of the reasoning behind the cited post.